# Groovy with method in pipeline DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a few classes in the shared library where we have to access the pipeline steps using the DSL object, so I thought he below code would work:

*Version 1*

```
class T {
    def dsl

    def T(def dsl) {
        this.dsl = dsl
    }

    def F() {
        this.dsl.with {
            echo "Hello World"
        }
    }
}

new T(this).F()
```

However, it generates the below script security exception:

```
Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object (T echo java.lang.String). Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object (T echo java.lang.String)
```

It looks like `dsl.with { echo ... }` doesn't translate to `dsl.echo` and instead it results in a lookup of the `echo` method on the `class T`. Assuming it is some closure delegate issue, I tried the below, and it still didn't work (same error as above):

*Version 2*

```
def withDsl(def body) {
    body.delegate = this
    this.with body
}

class T {
    def dsl

    def T(def dsl) {
        this.dsl = dsl
    }

    def F() {
        dsl.withDsl {
            echo "Hello World"
        }
    }
}

new T(this).F()
```

It finally worked when I created a wrapper on top of DSL and created methods that simply delegated the calls to DSL. I also had to modify the closure's delegate to get it working:

*Version 3*

```
class MyDsl {
    def dsl

    def MyDsl(def dsl) {
        this.dsl = dsl
    }

    def echo(msg) {
        dsl.echo msg        
    }
}

def withDsl(def body) {
    def mydsl = new MyDsl(this)
    body.delegate = mydsl
    mydsl.with body
}

class T {
    def dsl

    def T(def dsl) {
        this.dsl = dsl
    }

    def F() {
        dsl.withDsl {
            echo "Hello World"
        }
    }
}

new T(this).F()
```

Can anyone explain why the first two versions wouldn't work? Is there something I can do to avoid creating the wrapper class (which would be painful)?